# List all postgres databases resident on existing hosts

Tags: postgresql

Doing some housekeeping here, and I can generate a query that lists all resident hosts on our network here, i.e.

```
SELECT * 
FROM hosttable 
ORDER BY hostname;
```

I'd like to then take that output and generate a list of all Postgres databases resident on each host.  Keep in mind we have a minimum of a 2k hosts resident in our infrastructure.  I'm assuming a basic loop would work here, just not sure how to tie in the list results from first query as a looped variable in the find all databases query.

Comment: Not enough information here to make the question clear.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for an [inner join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN) in SQL.